# How effortlessly can universities check where you logged in? What other IT details can they determine?

Tags: technology

Assume you're accessing your university Canvas LMS and Intranet (**is this the correct term?**) —  e.g.  your university email, library website, etc... — normally, without VPN or proxy. Assume you haven't revealed anything about your locations or Internet details to university staff.

How readily or handily can university staff ***on their own*** deduce which city you logged in, if they can do this at all?

And how much can university staff deduce? IP address? ISP?

Comment: Who is "university staff"? IT services? Your course instructors? Some random professor? Also, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you asking us if you can easily get caught lying to your professors about your location?

Comment: Does the university run its own servers, or does it contract out the provision of online services to some other organisation(s)?

Comment: This seems like a [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470)-type question, since "university" could be replaced with any other website or organization.

Comment: A professor usually won't have access to the required resources. IT staff would. If your chair has a separate network (ours does) which you were accessing, it might be easy to find your IP (=geolocation to some degree, ISP and so on) for them as well. What's the issue though?

Comment: This would be dependent on the specific software in use, configuration settings chosen by the institution, institutional policies and local laws, technical skill of the staff in question... there is no general answer at all.